# How can I make my function return a double without changing type Metric?

Tags: haskell, type-conversion, sqrt

I have a function 'distance' that calculates the distance between two points.
my problem is that the function should be of type Metric, a type which returns a  Double while my sqrt within the function returns a Float.
This is my code:

```
    type Metric a = Point a -> Point a -> Double
    type Point a = (a, a)
    distance :: Floating a => Metric a
    distance (a1,b1) (a2, b2) = sqrt ((a*a)+(b*b))
       where a = a2 - a1
             b = b2 - b1
```

I know if a write Metric as Point a -> Point a -> a will solve my problem  but I need to use Metric as it is
I've also looked up for how to convert float to double in Haskell but did not found anything helpful

Comment: `sqrt` does not return a `Float`, it returns a value of the same type as that of the parameter, and that is an instance of `Floating` (note that `Floating` is a typeclass, and *not* the same as `Float`, which is a type). You can here specialize your `distance` function to `distance :: Metric Double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my problem is that the function should be of type `Metric`, a type which returns a `Double` while my `sqrt` within the function returns a `Float`.

`sqrt` does *not* return a `Float`, it returns a value of the same type as that of the parameter, and that is an instance of `Floating` (note that `Floating` is a typeclass, and *not* the same as `Float`, which is a type). It thus has as type [**`sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:sqrt).

You can here specialize your `distance` function to `distance :: Metric Double`:

```
distance :: Metric Double
distance (a1,b1) (a2, b2) = sqrt ((a*a)+(b*b))
    where a = a2 - a1
          b = b2 - b1
```

That being said, it might make more sense to let the `Metric` return an `a`:

```
type Metric2 a = Point a -> Point a -> a
```

and then thus work with a `Floating a => Metric2 a`:

```
distance :: Floating a => Metric2 a
distance (a1,b1) (a2, b2) = sqrt ((a*a)+(b*b))
    where a = a2 - a1
          b = b2 - b1
```

Comment: oh, I get it now, it worked when I used Metric Double but yeah it makes more sense to let Metric return an a. Thanks a lot!!